# viewport iphone4/4s and media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I have a website which I have created a media query for a resolution of 480px in width.
The iphone 4 correctly picks up this version but for some reason it overhangs the page its not using the actual resolution of the iphone 4 which is 640px in width its using a width of 320px. (i read somewhere that it does for backward compatibility with apps developed for iphone 3)

Is there a way using a viewport or media query to correct this? Many Thanks Dave

This is my current viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=5.0; minimum-scale=0.5; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The viewport meta "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" currently only works on the android platform. As it stands there is no equivalent for iOS.

You can achieve something similar using a double pixel density media query to target the iPhone like

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}
```

and then scaling everything down in CSS.

If you go that route scaling everything on the site using % and EM's would probably save you a lot of work in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, do you know if there's an iphone 4 emulator that can recognize this? ive tried chromes ripple but it seems to ignore it? unless im doing something wrong?